# RallyRestToolkitForRuby - project_scope_up & project_scope_down don't seem to be working

Tags: ruby, rally

I am trying to query all stories within a project and its children using RallyRestToolkitForRuby. I am trying to use the code snippet below, the project_scope_up and project_scope_down don't seem to have a bearing on the results, results from projects outside the tree specified are included.  What is incorrect here ?

```
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username]   = "xxxxxxxxxx"
config[:password]   = "xxxxxxxxx"
config[:workspace]  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
config[:project]    = "xxxxxxxxx"
config[:headers]    = headers 
RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
startdate = DateTime.parse "2013-02-20T00:00:00.000"
enddate = DateTime.parse "2013-02-23T00:00:00.000"
query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "hierarchicalrequirement"
query.fetch = "Iteration,Capitalizeable,CapBucket,FormattedID,DirectChildrenCount,RevisionHistory,Revisions"
query.page_size = 20       #optional - default is 200
query.limit = 20          #optional - default is 99999
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down= true
query.query_string = "((LastUpdateDate > \"#{startdate.to_s}\") AND (LastUpdateDate < \"#{enddate.to_s}\"))"
results = @rally.find(query)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have above, you don't appear to have a project set for the scoping - make sure you have a line setting query.project = something like:
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.25/project/12345.js" }

or if you had a project object stored in a variable:
myproject = @rally.find_project(workspace, "Project Name")
query.project = myproject

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - that worked - thought this line  => config[:project]    = "xxxxxxxxx" would take care of the project, did not realize that it has to be set at the query level.

Comment: This helped SO much.  I was having the same issue and had the same assumptions about project scoping that @user2038295 was having.